# How to replace words in my posts and saved new words

Tags: functions, customization

i need replace words in my posts and saved new words after delete code in my functions

i use this code for replace

```
<?php

function replace_text_wps($text){
$replace = array(
// ‘WORD TO REPLACE’ => ‘REPLACE WORD WITH THIS’
'wp' => '<img href="#"><a href="#">wordpress</a>',

);
$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=artist', 'replace_text_wps');
?>
```

this code is ok and replaced my words but if
delete this code in my functions new words not saved

i want one time replaced all words and save and delete code

how to that this ?

sorry , i can't good speaking english

Comment: Is this a one-time thing you want to do, or is it a function you need to use over again on a regular basis?

Comment: @CC just on-time , and after replaced words i want delete this code in functions

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time "patch" to update your database for word replacement, I find that [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) from interconnectit.com is excellent.  Be sure to have a backup of your database first, just in case.

An alternative would be to write a plugin that pulls the content from each post, does the filter, then updates the post by saving it back to the database.  Your code is only filtering the content when it is being displayed, you are missing the steps of actually modifying the content and saving it again.

The DB-level word replacement routine is much more efficient, especially if this is a one-time event.  The tool will allow you to target specific tables, so you don't inadvertently change text in other than the `_posts` table.

Comment: yea its true , but i have 3600 line code :( , There is no other solution to this ?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to create a simple plugin that first gets a list of all posts in the database ( `get_posts()` ), then steps through each post and retrieves the post content ( `get_post()` ), then modifies the content and updates the post in the database ( `wp_update_post()` )

Comment: By changing the code gets the job done function ????`replace_text_wps($text){
$replace = array(
// ‘WORD TO REPLACE’ => ‘REPLACE WORD WITH THIS’
'wp' => '<img href="#"><a href="#">wordpress</a>',

);
$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=artist', 'replace_text_wps');`

Comment: no - do not use the `add_filter` hooks method.  Instead create a plugin and in your main function for the plugin, run it based on the `add_action` 'init' hook.  See the steps I laid out in my prior comment.  That is what your new plugin should do.